# Using the ampscript ClaimRow DE function, cannot populate email address in DE col., in my case I display 2 unique codes or serial numbers per email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

[![Data Extension screenshot with 2 columns unique serial numbers[][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/608b6.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JuVr.png)

I am not sure why the **Email column** is not being populated with the subscriber **email address**, for the *coupon codes/serial numbers (OutboundSerialNumber & InboundSerialNumber)*, each subscriber should get 2 unique coupon codes in their email.

Example:
**Outbound = Y1203HZ1 and
Inbound = Z13423FG1**

```ampscript
%%[
var @GetsubscriberID,@InBoundserialNumber,@OutBoundserialNumber,@rows, @serialNRow,@GetsubsEmail

  set @GetsubsEmail=AttributeValue(emailAddr)

  set @rows = LookupRows("2023-DE-Name-CouponCodes", "IsClaimed", "False")

  if rowcount(@rows) > 0 then

set @serialNRow = ClaimRow("2023-DE-Name-CouponCodes","IsClaimed", "subscriberID", SubscriberID,"Email",@GetsubsEmail)

if empty(@serialNRow) then raiseError("Serial Number Row not available")

else

set @OutBoundserialNumber = field(@serialNRow,"OutboundSerialNumber")
AND set @InBoundserialNumber = field(@serialNRow,"InboundSerialNumber")

endif

else raiseError("Serial Number not available")

endif
]%%
```

Any suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//missing double quote in AttributeValue:
set @GetsubsEmail=AttributeValue("emailAddr")